# How to convert string to tuple using `reads`?

Tags: string, haskell

In GHCi, I try to read string as tuple.

```
>reads "(1,2)" :: [(Integer),(Integer)]
```

which outputs the error:

> Couldn't match type [Char] with Integer
>   expected type: [(Integer,Integer)]
>   actual type: [(Integer,String)]

The example I found online, and works is:

```
>reads "(34, True),abc" :: [((Integer,Bool),String)]
[((34,True),",abc")]
```

So why the one I try to create won't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to account for the trailing `String` which `reads` always produces.

```
> reads "(1,2)" :: [((Integer,Integer),String)]
[((1,2),"")]
```

If you only want a single pair and are absolutely certain that the string parses correctly, use `read` instead

```
> read "(1,2)" :: (Integer,Integer)
(1,2)
```

Note that `read` (unlike `reads`) will crash your program on an invalid string. If you can not assume the string parses correctly, but you still want a single pair, use [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) instead form `Text.Read`.